# Find the dimensions of the nullspaces of two functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Exercise :** Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be linear functionals on an $n$-dimensional vectorspace $V$. Let $N_j$ be the null space of $f_j$, $j=1, 2$. Suppose that $f_1\neq 0\neq f_2$ and that $N_1\neq N_2$. Find the dimension of each of the spaces $N_1$, $N_2$, $N_1\cap N_2$ and $N_1+N_2$.

I was working through this problem and found a solution which seems alright to me, except for the fact that I made an assumption of which I don't think I'm allowed to make it. Namely that $f_1, f_2$ are part of a basis. But without this assumption I have no idea on how I do solve the problem.

**My attempt :** We know that there exists a basis $B=\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}$ of $V^*$, therefore $f_1, f_2$ are linearly independent. Then $\dim(N_1)=\dim(N_2)=n-1$, and also $\dim(N_1\cap N_2)=n-2, \dim(N_1+N_2)=n$.

Of course, it doesn't look very formal and needs a few more words, but the idea should be clear. If this is not the intended solution, what should I be looking at instead?

Comment: **Hint :** Use the rank-nullity theorem on $f_j:V\to \Bbb K$ to compute the dimensions of $N_1$ and $N_2$. There are not many possible values for $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f_j))$...

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Any linear functional will be of the form $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ for some $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R^n}$.